# Printing Max, Min and amount of elemments in and array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this code

```
        int results[] = new int[13];
        results[0]=19;
        results[1]=22;
        results[2]=21;
        results[3]=25;
        results[4]=32;
        results[5]=38;
        results[6]=16;
        results[7]=31;
        results[8]=30;
        results[9]=26;
        results[10]=19;
        results[11]=17;
        results[12]=23;
        for(int i=0;i<results.length;i++)
        System.out.println(results[lenght,Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE]);    
        
    }
}
```

How do I print the lenght of the array, the min value and the max malue all in a same array?

Comment: Hello, what kind of solution have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I've tried the one that is on the question but it didn't work, and I'm searching for more posible solutions, I'm really new to Java so is been rough

Comment: Compare the array elements inside the for loop to find the min and max. Use the array property *length* to get the amount of elements. The statement ```results[lenght,Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE]``` actually makes no sense

Comment: I suggest you to update you question following these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Integer>results2=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int result : results) {
        results2.add(result);
    }
    System.out.println("Minimum: " + Collections.min(results2));
    System.out.println("Maximum: " + Collections.max(results2));
    System.out.println("Amount of elements: " + results2.size());
```